# AJAX Success Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently trying to pop a bootstrap modal up on the success call of my AJAX post. But right now it's not popping up anything and the console error returns this 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' on the line with "**success: function(data) {**"

Here is the HTML

```
                        <div id="formkeep">
                            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="https://formkeep.com/f/46a86d397432" method="POST" id="beta-signup">
                              <input type="hidden" name="utf8" value="✓">
                              <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your Email">
                              <button class="btn" type="submit">Get Access</button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal fade" id="your-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" style="hidden">
                            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                <div class="modal-content">
                                    <div class="modal-header">

                                    </div>
                                    <div class="modal-body">

                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Javascript running it

```
<script>
$(function() {
  $('#beta-signup').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var formEl = $(this);
    var submitButton = $('input[type=submit]', formEl);

    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: formEl.prop('action'),
      accept: {
        javascript: 'application/javascript'
      },
      data: formEl.serialize(),
      beforeSend: function() {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
          }
    success: function(data) {
       $('#your-modal').modal('toggle');
      }
    }).done(function(data) {
      submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
    });
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: @keune semicolon or comma…

Answer (score 1):

You need a comma between each `key: value` pair in an object literal.

```
accept: {
    javascript: 'application/javascript'
},
```

You have one at the end of the line above

```
data: formEl.serialize(),
```

And on there

```
beforeSend: function() {
    submitButton.prop('disabled', 'disabled');
}
```

But you forgot it there

```
success: function(data) {
    $('#your-modal').modal('toggle');
}
```

So that is immediately after the previous value without the comma to separate it.